# Is there a resources where we can learn how to modify a program that doesn't use storyboard to use storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode4.3

Starting in iOs 5, we have this new feature called story board. Also the whole concept of viewController change.

Usually we created story board by making new project and voila, iOS set everything up.

Say I have a project that didn't use story board. Say I want it to use storyboard.

What kind of change I should make?

What are the best URLs or e-Book to learn more about using this storyboard and the new viewController paradigm?

Comment: [Apple iOS Developer doc for Adopting storyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/_index.html)

Comment: Please turn that into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apple iOS Developer doc for Adopting storyboard](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/Miscellaneous/RN-AdoptingStoryboards/_index.html)

http://maniacdev.com/ios-5-sdk-tutorial-and-guide/xcode-4-storyboard/

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

http://codingandcoffee.wordpress.com/2011/10/12/iphone-tutorial-one-introduction-to-storyboarding/

Comment: Actually answer the question. I'll wait just in case there is better answer but +1 already. Maybe there are other good resources?

Answer (score 0):

http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/07/simple-ios-5-tutorial-using-storyboard.html this is another source. Bala answer is also good.